# Inequality $\ln(1+x)\leq x^a$ on $\mathbb{R}_+$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $E=\{a\in\mathbb{R}_+,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+,\;\ln(1+x)\leq x^a\}$. Obviously $E\subset]0,1]$, since $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ as $x$ tends to $0$, $1\in E$ because it is known that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+,\;\ln(1+x)\leq x$. We have $\frac 12\in E$ because $\displaystyle\forall x\in\mathbb{R}_+^*,\; \frac{1}{1+x}\leq\frac 1{2\sqrt x}$. And $E$ is closed because if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of elements in $E$ which converges in $\mathbb{R}_+$ to $a_{\infty}$, then $a_\infty\in E$ (taking the limit in the inequality).
My questions are :

1. is $E$ an interval (and so $[\frac 12,1]\subset E$ easily) ?
2. can $\min(E)$ be explicitely given (and what is the unique solution in $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ of the equation $\ln(1+x)=x^{\min(E)}$) ?

Thank you.

Comment: If $a_1 \leq a \leq a_2$ the $x^{a_1}\wedge x^{a_2} \leq x^{a}$ for all $x \geq 0$ so $E$ is an interval.

Comment: Considering $a$ as variable we have increasing function.

Comment: Numerically, $\min (E) = 0.3798312 \ldots$

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean with $x^{a_1}\land x^{a_2}≤x^a$ @Kavi Rama Murthy ?

Comment: @Gary : yes, and I don't see this numbers in OEIS...

Comment: I am proving that if $a_1,a_2 \in E$ and $a$ lies between these two then $a$ is also in $E$.

Comment: @P.Fazioli The Inverse Symbolic Caculator does not identify it either.

Comment: Yes, ok, I have understood what $\land$ was meaning ! Thank you.

Comment: The $\min(E)$ can be computed as follows. Let $x_\star$ be the unique positive solution of $(e^x  - 1)\log (e^x  - 1) = xe^x \log x$. Then $$\min(E)=
\frac{{1 - e^{ - x_\star} }}{x_\star}.
$$ Numerically, $\min(E)=0.37983121492661090182261\ldots$.

Comment: Oh ok thank you Gary... how do you see that ?!